# Error while installing ltsp server package in fedora 12

Tags: fedora, linux, ltsp

i am using fedora 12, while i was installing ltsp(Linux terminal server project) server package, it told me that some more packages need to be installed with it as well, while downloading the packages i got the following error -

**Local Conflict between packages 
Test Transaction Errors: file /usr/share/man/man5/dhcp-eval.5.gz from install of dhcp-12:4.1.1-5.fc12.i686 conflicts with file from package dhclient-12:4.1.0p1-12.fc12.i686 file /usr/share/man/man5/dhcp-options.5.gz from install of dhcp-12:4.1.1-5.fc12.i686 conflicts with file from package dhclient-12:4.1.0p1-12.fc12.i686**

i also deleted all the dhcp packages from man5 directory, even then it is giving the same error msg. please help me with it

Answer (score 1):

It seems you hit file conflict problem in installed dhclient, when install dhcp package. File conflict means that you install package with same file location (e.g /usr/share/man/man5/dhcp-options.5.gz), but different md5sum.

RPM test file conflicts relying on its database and package,  not in existing files on filesystem.

Proposed solutions is:
1) If you install packages from vendor repository you should at first check upgrade installed dhclient/dhcp packages (via **yum install dhclient dhcp**). May be after upgrade md5sum of problem file will match.

2) Also you can deinstall conflicted package - **yum remove dhclient**. Note, that this command also remove packages, which depends on dhclient package.

3) Also you can try to use rpm --nodeps flags for installing/removing packages, but after such operation system will be inconsistent.